# Apollo Server: How can I add a custom endpoint for Stripe webhook?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have a graphql server that I want to add a custom endpoint for so that Stripe can communicate with it when a customer's Subscription status changes.

Currently, my index.js file looks like a typical Apollo Server set up:

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server";
import { connectDb } from "./models";

import schema from "./schema";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";
import contexts from "./contexts";

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    const { getCurrentUser } = contexts;

    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser(req);
    return { models, currentUser };
  },
});

connectDb().then(async () => {
  server.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }).then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
  });
});
```

So only `/graphql` is exposed.

How would I add a custom `POST /foobar` endpoint that does something similar to this? (source: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build#example-code)

```
// This example uses Express to receive webhooks
const app = require('express')();

// Use body-parser to retrieve the raw body as a buffer
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Match the raw body to content type application/json
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  let event;

  try {
    event = JSON.parse(request.body);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
      // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
      break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
      const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
      // handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      return response.status(400).end();
  }

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.json({received: true});
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Running on port 8000'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to migrate from `apollo-server` to `apollo-server-express`. Then you could add whatever additional endpoints you need. If you don't want to use Express, you can also utilize any of the other [available integrations](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server#installation-integrations).

Comment: Awesome I’ll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @bigpatato hi can you help me abput this question ? i want to the same :/ and i cant add spesific endpoint my apollo server

Answer (score 2):

here's how I set this up for anyone who stumbles on this. I'm using `apollo-server-express`:

```js
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { pinoLogger } from './lib/logger.js';
import { graphql } from './api/graphql/server.js';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

// this is where I set up the ApolloServer with it's resolvers and schema
graphql({ app, httpServer });

app.post('/webhooks/stripe', async (req, res) => {
  const event = req.body;
  const logger = pinoLogger.child({ stripeEventId: event.id });
  logger.info('Received stripe event', { event });
  res.sendStatus(200);
})

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  pinoLogger.info(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`);
});
```